# JMS serializer returns malformed JSON

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

As title says, I have a problem with JMS serializer running on Symfony 2.7 which returns a malformed JSON. This happens only when database becomes bigger.

I made a simple function which returns the whole database serialized in JSON, sometimes is useful for me to check some data.

Basically I have this function

```
function asJson($serializationGroup = null)

{
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

    $serGroups = array('Default');
    if (is_string($serializationGroup)) {
        $serGroups[] = $serializationGroup;
    }
    if (is_array($serializationGroup)) {
        foreach($serializationGroup as $sg) $serGroups[] = $sg;
    }

    $serializationContext = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($serGroups);
    $serializationContext->setSerializeNull(true);
    return $serializer->serialize($this, 'json', $serializationContext);
}
```

which returns a JSON containing data associated to given serialization groups. Then I call it from a Controller giving all my serialization groups in order to serialize the entire db.

But, as I said, when my db becomes bigger I get a malformed JSON. Moreover the error is always different

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at
>   line 1 column 182085 of the JSON data
>
> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in
>   object at line 1 column 367466 of the JSON data
>
> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at
>   line 1 column 1158 of the JSON data

I tried to analyze the JSON and I noticed that it is totally corrupted after the error line.. Something like:

```
"commands_deletedse," <-- here starts the error, the rest is malformed
active ":true,"
readonly ":false,"
running ":false,"
...
```

---

**UPDATE**

It seems to work on another PC having MySQL 5.7 while the bug is present on another PC having MySQL 5.5. I don't know if it has something to do with..

---

**UPDATE 2**

It seems to work on the same PC but from Symfony command, hence I would say it has something to do with nginx configuration. In fact I even noticed that calling it from website works 1/10 time, so I would say the error comes from something like a timeout configuration or so. I use nginx + php-fpm.

---

**UPDATE 3**

I tried to starting the Symfony internal webserver and then call the controller function but I got the same error. I'm starting have no idea about what should I test..

Any thought?

Comment: This task looks ridiculous so unless developers of JMS Serializer show up, it will be really hard to get an answer. Are you sure you need to extract your whole database?

Comment: Yes, it is sometimes useful for me..

Comment: This seems like a poor idea.  If your database contains binary data or blobs or other things like that, you're going to have a bad time.  Wouldn't it be better to use the database's own tools for dumping the database to a .sql file, and then operate on that instead?

Comment: @JasonRoman actually I have no binary/blob data, so it works well, but something is changed in db and is not working anymore. It is a comfortable way for me since the project is for an internal system linked to a smartphone app only locally reachable and is useful to check data that I'm sending to app itself.

Comment: Couldn't you then internally run a sql dump command and use that instead?

Comment: @JasonRoman it is something hard reading data from sql since I have a lot of entities and relations with table inheritance using Doctrine. Anyway I noticed that it works on another PC having mysql 5.7 while the one that is experiencing problem has mysql 5.5. I'm going to update the question as well.